# Execution failed for task ':app:externalNativeBuildDebug' Android.mk

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk

I'm trying to run this project https://github.com/eyetrackingDB/GazeTrackingFramework

I installed Android Studio 2.3.3, with NDK 15.1.4119039, and Gradle version 3.3, and Android plugin version 2.3.3.

I have a problem in linking phase.
I got this message:

```
Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:externalNativeBuildDebug'.
> Build command failed.
  Error while executing process /Users/younghov/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/ndk-build with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=/Users/younghov/AndroidStudioProjects/GazeTrackingFramework-master_7/app/src/main/jni/Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=/Users/younghov/AndroidStudioProjects/GazeTrackingFramework-master_7/app/src/main/jni/Application.mk APP_ABI=mips64 NDK_ALL_ABIS=mips64 NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-21 NDK_OUT=/Users/younghov/AndroidStudioProjects/GazeTrackingFramework-master_7/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=/Users/younghov/AndroidStudioProjects/GazeTrackingFramework-master_7/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/lib /Users/younghov/AndroidStudioProjects/GazeTrackingFramework-master_7/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/mips64/libeyetab_tracker.so}
  Android NDK: WARNING:/Users/younghov/AndroidStudioProjects/GazeTrackingFramework-master_7/app/src/main/jni/Android.mk:eyetab_tracker: non-system libraries in linker flags: -lopencv_java    
  Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES    
  Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the    
  Android NDK:     current module    
  [mips64] Compile++      : eyetab_tracker <= eyetab_tracker.cpp
  /bin/sh: /Users/younghov/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/mips64el-linux-android-4.8/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/mips64el-linux-android-g++: No such file or directory
  make: *** [/Users/younghov/AndroidStudioProjects/GazeTrackingFramework-master_7/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/mips64/objs-debug/eyetab_tracker/eyetab_tracker.o] Error 127


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Here is my Android.mk file:

```
#Set the local path to the JNI folder
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

# INCLUDE OPENCV AND OWN MODULE
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

include /Users/younghov/Downloads/OpenCV-2.4.9-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_MODULE    := eyetab_tracker
LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=  eyetab_tracker.cpp EyeTabTracker/GazeSettingsEyeTab.cpp EyeTabTracker/GazeTrackerEyeTab.cpp EyeTabTracker/src_eyetab/erase_specular.cpp EyeTabTracker/src_eyetab/eye_center_isophotes.cpp EyeTabTracker/src_eyetab/eye_center_combined.cpp EyeTabTracker/src_eyetab/fit_ellipse.cpp EyeTabTracker/src_eyetab/utils.cpp EyeTabTracker/src_eyetab/gaze_geometry.cpp EyeTabTracker/src_eyetab/gaze_smoothing.cpp EyeTabTracker/src_eyetab/get_poss_limb_pts.cpp EyeTabTracker/src_eyetab/get_eyelids.cpp EyeTabTracker/src_eyetab/gaze_system.cpp EyeTabTracker/src_eyetab/eye_detect.cpp EyeTabTracker/src_eyelike/findEyeCenter.cpp EyeTabTracker/src_eyelike/helpers.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -lm -llog -landroid LOCAL_CFLAGS += -std=c++11 -I/Users/younghov/Downloads/tbb2017_20170604oss/include
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Add prebuilt libavcodec
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libavcodec
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := prebuilt/libavcodec.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Add prebuilt libavdevice
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libavdevice
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := prebuilt/libavdevice.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Add prebuilt libavfilter
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libavfilter
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := prebuilt/libavfilter.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Add prebuilt libavformat
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libavformat
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := prebuilt/libavformat.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Add prebuilt libavutil
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libavutil
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := prebuilt/libavutil.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Add prebuilt libffmpeg
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libffmpeg
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := prebuilt/libffmpeg.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Add prebuilt libjniavcodec
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libjniavcodec
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := prebuilt/libjniavcodec.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Add prebuilt libjniavdevice
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libjniavdevice
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := prebuilt/libjniavdevice.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Add prebuilt libjniavfilter
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libjniavfilter
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := prebuilt/libjniavfilter.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Add prebuilt libjniavformat
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libjniavformat
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := prebuilt/libjniavformat.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Add prebuilt libjniavutil
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libjniavutil
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := prebuilt/libjniavutil.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Add prebuilt libjnicvkernels
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libjnicvkernels
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := prebuilt/libjnicvkernels.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Add prebuilt libjniopencv_calib3d
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libjniopencv_calib3d
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := prebuilt/libjniopencv_calib3d.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Add prebuilt libjniopencv_contrib
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libjniopencv_contrib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := prebuilt/libjniopencv_contrib.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Add prebuilt libjniopencv_core
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libjniopencv_core
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := prebuilt/libjniopencv_core.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Add prebuilt libjniopencv_features2d
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libjniopencv_features2d
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := prebuilt/libjniopencv_features2d.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Add prebuilt libjniopencv_flann
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libjniopencv_flann
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := prebuilt/libjniopencv_flann.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Add prebuilt libjniopencv_highgui
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libjniopencv_highgui
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := prebuilt/libjniopencv_highgui.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Add prebuilt libjniopencv_imgproc
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libjniopencv_imgproc
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := prebuilt/libjniopencv_imgproc.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Add prebuilt libjniopencv_legacy
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libjniopencv_legacy
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := prebuilt/libjniopencv_legacy.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Add prebuilt libjniopencv_ml
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libjniopencv_ml
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := prebuilt/libjniopencv_ml.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Add prebuilt libjniopencv_nonfree
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libjniopencv_nonfree
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := prebuilt/libjniopencv_nonfree.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Add prebuilt libjniopencv_objdetect
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libjniopencv_objdetect
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := prebuilt/libjniopencv_objdetect.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Add prebuilt libjniopencv_photo
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libjniopencv_photo
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := prebuilt/libjniopencv_photo.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Add prebuilt libjniopencv_stitching
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libjniopencv_stitching
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := prebuilt/libjniopencv_stitching.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Add prebuilt libjniopencv_superres
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libjniopencv_superres
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := prebuilt/libjniopencv_superres.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Add prebuilt libjniopencv_video
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libjniopencv_video
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := prebuilt/libjniopencv_video.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Add prebuilt libjniopencv_videostab
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libjniopencv_videostab
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := prebuilt/libjniopencv_videostab.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Add prebuilt libjnipostproc
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libjnipostproc
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := prebuilt/libjnipostproc.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Add prebuilt libjniswresample
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libjniswresample
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := prebuilt/libjniswresample.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Add prebuilt libjniswscale
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libjniswscale
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := prebuilt/libjniswscale.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Add prebuilt libopencv_calib3d
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libopencv_calib3d
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := prebuilt/libopencv_calib3d.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Add prebuilt libopencv_contrib
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libopencv_contrib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := prebuilt/libopencv_contrib.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Add prebuilt libopencv_core
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libopencv_core
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := prebuilt/libopencv_core.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Add prebuilt libopencv_features2d
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libopencv_features2d
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := prebuilt/libopencv_features2d.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Add prebuilt libopencv_flann
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libopencv_flann
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := prebuilt/libopencv_flann.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Add prebuilt libopencv_gpu
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libopencv_gpu
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := prebuilt/libopencv_gpu.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Add prebuilt libopencv_highgui
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libopencv_highgui
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := prebuilt/libopencv_highgui.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Add prebuilt libopencv_imgproc
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libopencv_imgproc
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := prebuilt/libopencv_imgproc.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Add prebuilt libopencv_legacy
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libopencv_legacy
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := prebuilt/libopencv_legacy.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Add prebuilt libopencv_ml
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libopencv_ml
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := prebuilt/libopencv_ml.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Add prebuilt libopencv_nonfree
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libopencv_nonfree
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := prebuilt/libopencv_nonfree.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Add prebuilt libopencv_objdetect
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libopencv_objdetect
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := prebuilt/libopencv_objdetect.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Add prebuilt libopencv_photo
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libopencv_photo
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := prebuilt/libopencv_photo.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Add prebuilt libopencv_stitching
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libopencv_stitching
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := prebuilt/libopencv_stitching.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Add prebuilt libopencv_superres
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libopencv_superres
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := prebuilt/libopencv_superres.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Add prebuilt libopencv_video
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libopencv_video
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := prebuilt/libopencv_video.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Add prebuilt libopencv_videostab
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libopencv_videostab
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := prebuilt/libopencv_videostab.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Add prebuilt libpostproc
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libpostproc
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := prebuilt/libpostproc.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Add prebuilt libswresample
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libswresample
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := prebuilt/libswresample.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Add prebuilt libswscale
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libswscale
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := prebuilt/libswscale.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Add prebuilt libtbb
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libtbb
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := prebuilt/libtbb.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Am i missing something or have some incompatible issue with version?